# logical error in SQLite databse, unable to find such column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

my logcat file :

    `07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.snotes/com.example.snotes.SHow}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _idmoneyreasonDAte: , while compiling: SELECT _idmoneyreasonDAte FROM MONEY_TABLE
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _idmoneyreasonDAte: , while compiling: SELECT _idmoneyreasonDAte FROM MONEY_TABLE
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
07-31 22:26:38.600: E/AndroidRuntime(375):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)`

my java file``

```
  import android.content.ContentValues;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.SQLException;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

  public class SAve { 
      public static final String KEY_ID ="_id";
      public static final String KEY_MONEY ="money";
      public static final String KEY_REASON ="reason";
      public static final String KEY_DATE ="DAte";

      private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="SAVEdb";
      private static final String DATABASE_TABLE ="MONEY_TABLE";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;


      private dbHelper ourHelper;
      private Context ourContext;
      private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

      private static class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public dbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
            arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" ("+ KEY_ID+" INTEGER   
         PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +KEY_MONEY
                    +" TEXT NOT NULL, "+ KEY_REASON+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+KEY_DATE+" TEXT         

         NOT NULL); "
                    );
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

            arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(arg0);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

      }
 public SAve (Context c){
     ourContext = c;
 }

 public SAve open() throws SQLException{
     ourHelper = new dbHelper(ourContext);
     ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     return this;
 }



 public void close(){
     ourHelper.close();
 }

public long creatEntry(String money, String reason, String daTe) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_MONEY, money);
    cv.put(KEY_REASON, reason);
    cv.put(KEY_DATE, daTe);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns= new String[]{ KEY_ID  + KEY_MONEY + KEY_REASON + KEY_DATE  };
    Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result ="";

    int irow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
    int imoney = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONEY);
    int ireason = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REASON);
    int idate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); c.isAfterLast() ; c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(irow)+ " " + c.getString(imoney) + " " +     
       c.getString(ireason) + " " + c.getString(idate)+ "\n";

    }

    return result;
}
```

}``

dummy text 
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk

cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk

cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
v
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk
cldslcnlsdncksddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdvksadkvbsvbskdvsdvbklsdbvlsbdkvlsbadvklbsadj sk nskd vkjbvksbvklsbdkjvlskvbskdvbksbv.sabvk

Comment: It's a bit lazy to dump a stack trace onto Stack Overflow and expect help. If you'd read the trace, you could have easily discerned the source of the error yourself (i.e. malformed SQL code).

Comment: Even a bit disrespectful actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQLiteException: no such column: _idmoneyreasonDAte: 
[...] while compiling: SELECT _idmoneyreasonDAte FROM MONEY_TABLE
```

You are selecting all values of a column (called `_idmoneyreasonDAte`) that doesn't exist in the table `MONEY_TABLE`.

The bug is here:

```
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns= new String[]{ KEY_ID  + KEY_MONEY + KEY_REASON + KEY_DATE  };
    Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

You are concatenating `KEY_ID  + KEY_MONEY + KEY_REASON + KEY_DATE`, which actually gives `"_idmoneyreasonDAte"`.

Funny, I like it.